# Passing a json array to javascript function in a jade rendered page

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a json array being passed to a jade template.

This template then runs through the array adding rows to the html output.

However a new requirement no needs that json object to be passed to a javascript function, so I tried:

```
- var json = JSON.stringify(rows);
input.medium.success.button.error(type='submit', id='update_details', value= sendCommandLabel, onclick='sendCommand(' + json + ')')
```

which gives the following output (the full array omitted from brevity):

```
<input type="submit" id="update_details" value="Send Command" onclick="sendCommand([{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;id1;,&quot;param1&quot;:value1, ... &quot;}])">
```

Which is not useful as I am want to use this output in the javascript function and as it stands I can't consume it.

I am hoping I am missing something simple as my other option is to recreate the json array by looping through the objects in the renderer to recreate it!

**UPDATE**: I modified the code so instead of passing the array to the function, the array is hardcoded into the function while the jade page was being compiled. So this:

```
    function sendStopCommandToAllSensors()
    {
        var hardcode = !{JSON.stringify(rows)};
```

became

```
    function sendStopCommandToAllSensors()
    {
        var hardcode = [{"id":"id1", ... }, {"id":"id2", ... }];
```

But that still didn't work.

Puzzlingly adding a couple of simple `alert`s in there showed that there was the correct number of objects (later confirmed that there by cutting and pasting the resultant string directly into code and then manually adding a third object).

```
    alert(hardcode.length);     // displays 2
    alert("rows: " + hardcode); // displays [object Object],[object Object]
```

Which is why in the loop that follows the

```
    for (var row in hardcode)
    {
        alert("row: " + row); // displays 0 or 1, not an object

        if (row.active == 1)
        {
            alert("Reached here"); // never reached
```

the final line is never reached.

**UPDATE II**: By `stringify`ing `hardcode` I can output the human readable json.

```
alert("rows: " + JSON.stringify(hardcode));
```

**Why is the code not seemingly parsing the array correctly and what to I do need to do correct it?**

**UPDATE III**: I now having it working by using a two step traditional loop and assignment.

```
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
        {
            var row = rows[i];
```

So the question seems to be now, **why didn't the `for..in` loop work as expected?**

Comment: `for...in` only works for objects with enumerable properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this, but I was going through similar problem I think.

But I am totally ok with JSON.stringify method, which was your first solution. It looks ugly in generated hmtl, but I found it useful in my case.
At least I think I understood it right and you are not trying to do some kind of magic what I can't absorb yet.

if

```
rows=[{id:id,param:param},{id:id2,param:param2}]
```

JADE:

```
- var json = JSON.stringify(rows);
input(type='submit', onclick='myFunction(' + json + ')')
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(myRows) {  
  console.log(myRows[0].id);
  console.log(myRows[0].param);
  console.log(myRows[1].id);
  console.log(myRows[1].param);
  .
  .
```

at least it is ok in what I am working on.

I hope I didn't wrote pile of nonsense :)